# Xcode 13.3 Build DocC Command CompileDocumentation failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, docc

Xcode Build DocC Document with Product-Build Documentation failed

Command CompileDocumentation failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: In its current state this question doesn't contain enough information for anyone to be able to answer it. The only information is that some error occurred but not what that error.